# Missing component identification

Tags: capacitor, resistors, components, remote, trimmer

I have a remote controller whose antenna is de-soldered and it seems there was a capacitor or a resistor (see red circle).

Can anyone help me to understand what component could be the missing one? I thought a capacitor similar to others close but I'm not sure.

Thanks to anyone can help!

[image]

Comment: I think you are SOL on this.  Without a schematic diagram, all anyone could do is guess.  Even if you knew if a resistor, a capacitor, or even an inductor belonged there, that wouldn't tell you the value.  To my eyes, the part was not properly desoldered but seems to have been broken and then fallen out.

Comment: It looks like the end caps are still stuck in the solder.

Comment: You'd need to find the model number of the remote control, then search the internet to find a schematic diagram for it.  Or, find an identical one then remove and measure the missing part.

Comment: why are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

> *Can anyone help me to understand what component could be the missing
> one?*

I think there's a good basis for believing the capacitor was deliberately de-soldered in order to improve the tuning of the antenna or oscillator that it uses. Many designs leave space to add components through a "select-on-test" process and, quite often some components are fitted and then removed in the same process.

> *I thought a capacitor similar to others close but I'm not sure.*

Given the type of circuit, more than likely it is a capacitor but there's no-way that it might be similar to others that surround it.